# Simple linear interpolation in Swift

Tags: python, swift, numpy

I'm converting a script from Python to Swift. In the original Python code I'm doing a simple interpolation between two lists, using Numpy `interp` in the following format:

```
>>> xp = [1, 2, 3]
>>> fp = [3, 2, 0]
>>> np.interp(2.5, xp, fp)
1.0
```

This is from the Numpy documentation, not my actual code, but this is exactly what I require and have used in the Python script. **In short, I have the x and y axes as arrays, and I want to do one-dimensional interpolation to evaluate an x coordinate.**

All this works great with Python/Numpy, but I cannot get it to work in Swift. The Accelerate vDSP framework has `linearInterpolate(VectorA, VectorB, using: X)`, but it returns an array rather than a single value.

```
var y = vDSP.linearInterpolate([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 0.0], using: 2.5)
```

Results in:

```
[6, 2, -4.5]
```

This should be very simple, and I guess one option is to just write my own function. But surely there must be an easy one-liner way to do this? I'm new to Swift and it feels like I'm missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rendition of [`linearInterpolate(_:_:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3241006-linearinterpolate) is designed to solve a very different problem:

> For example, the following code creates two arrays, `vectorA` and `vectorB`, that contain sine waves:
>
> ```swift
> let n = 1024
>
> let vectorA: [Float] = (0 ... n).map {
>     return 2 + sin(Float($0) * 0.07)
> }
>
> let vectorB: [Float] = (0 ... n).map {
>     return -2 + sin(Float($0) * 0.03)
> }
> ```
>
> Use `linearInterpolate(_:_:using:)` with an interpolation constant of `0.5` to generate a new vector that's the average of the two sine waves:
>
> ```swift
> let result = vDSP.linearInterpolate(vectorA, vectorB,
>                                     using: 0.5)
> ```
>
> The following figure visualizes the two source vectors: the blue lines at the top and bottom, and the interpolation result: the red line in the center:
>
> [image]

---

The [`linearInterpolate(elementsOf:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3241010-linearinterpolate) does something closer to what you are looking for (though you only supply the *y* values, and it assumes integer *x* index values).

So consider:

```py
>>> xp = [0, 1, 2]
>>> fp = [3, 2, 0]
>>> np.interp(1.5, xp, fp)
1.0
```

The equivalent vDSP call might be:

```
let z = vDSP.linearInterpolate(elementsOf: [3.0, 2.0, 0.0], using: [1.5])
```

> [1.0]

Now that employs implicit *x* values that are a zero-based index (e.g. 0, 1, 2, etc.), thus I tweaked your Python example to use zero-based index values for *x.*

So, this vDSP solution is a special case of interpolation between neighboring values, but I don't know whether that is sufficient, or whether you needed a more general solution (for arbitrary *x* values in your input). If so, yes, you might just have to write your own little helper function.

---

Here is an example of a more general solution that retrieves for only one *x* value:

```swift
func linearInterpolate<S, T>(_ sequenceX: S, _ sequenceY: S, at index: T) -> T? where S: Sequence, S.Element == T, T: FloatingPoint {
    var xIterator = sequenceX.makeIterator()
    var yIterator = sequenceY.makeIterator()

    guard
        var previousX = xIterator.next(),
        var previousY = yIterator.next()
    else {
        return nil
    }

    while true {
        if index == previousX { return previousY }

        guard
            let x = xIterator.next(),
            let y = yIterator.next()
        else {
            return nil
        }

        if (index > previousX && index < x) || (index > x && index < previousX) {
            let percent = (index - previousX) / (x - previousX)
            return previousY + percent * (y - previousY)
        }

        previousX = x
        previousY = y
    }
}
```

and

```
let xp: [Double] = [1, 2, 3]
let fp: [Double] = [3, 2, 0]

if let y = linearInterpolate(xp, fp, at: 2.5) {
    print(y) // 1.0
}
```